# Can't get observation-wise factor scores from psych package

Tags: r, factor-analysis, spearman-rho

After R reads the data, say-

```
v1 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,5,6)
v2 <- c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,2,1,3,4,3,3,3,4,6,5)
v3 <- c(3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,4,6)
v4 <- c(3,3,4,3,3,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,5,6,4)
v5 <- c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,6,4,5)
v6 <- c(1,1,1,2,1,3,3,3,4,3,1,1,1,2,1,6,5,4)
m1 <- cbind(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6)
```

if I run-

```
factanal(~v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6, factors = 3, scores = "Bartlett")$scores
```

I can get observation-wise factor scores. But when I do this-

```
r<-cor(m1)
library(psych)
fa<-fac(r,nfactors=3,rotate="varimax", scores="Bartlett")
fa$score
```

I can't get individual-wise factor scores. Is it possible to get individual-wise factor scores using psych? Actually I need to use psych, because I need to put spearman's rank correlation matrix as the starting point for factor analysis. Kindly suggest me.

Thank You

Comment: You'll probably need to provide raw data, and not just a correlation matrix, if you want to compute regression scores. Try this instead: `fac(data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6), nfactors=3, rotate="varimax", scores="Bartlett")$scores`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Blain, I'm not R user so can't be an expert. Anyway... What I see from your code is that you input correlation matrix in place of initial case-wise data into `fac`. This way you can't hope to obtain case-wise factor scores! What you can obtain at best is the matrix of regressional coefficients by which the scores can be computed.

A separate concern is you plan to base your future factor analysis on Spearman correlation. I don't know `psych` and its options but I *suspect* that the package just will process such matrix as if it were Pearson correlation. Linear factor analysis is *mathematically* based on Pearson correlations (or on covariances or cosines or sum-of-squares-and-cross-products, or on *inferred* Pearson correlations such as tetrachoric ones) and is not meant for rank correlations. The only justification to use Spearman instead of Pearson in the analysis would be your belief that the former reflects *underlying* linear relationships more accurately than the observed Pearson coefficient. But whence can you get this certainty?

Comment: (+1) I can confirm that Pearson correlations are used, by default. (With raw data, pairwise correlations are computed.) The 6 by 3 matrix of beta weights is returned as `fa$weights`, in the present case.