# Why is Pearson Principal Component Analysis so much more common than Spearman or Kendall PCA?

Tags: correlation, pca, pearson-r, spearman-rho

As I understand it, Pearson PCA finds eigenvectors of the Pearson correlation matrix. The result is a coordinate system with dimensions that are linearly uncorrelated.

But, a Spearman PCA does this with the Spearman correlation matrix, and therefore the dimensions are not only linearly uncorrelated, but monotonically uncorrelated. At least to me, that seems much stronger.

Is my understanding wrong? Why is Pearson PCA so much more popular than Spearman PCA? And by popular, I mean that most libraries only ever provide the former.

I do understand that Pearson *invented* PCA, but that was more than 100 years ago.

Comment: One answer among several is that if you want Spearman PCA, you just need to calculate ranks first and then feed them to PCA. So, in terms of software provision, there is no point in separate routines (functions, commands, whatever), as whatever software allows PCA would typically provide rank calculations.  A looser but more fundamental answer is that modelling predicting ranks is usually less interesting and less useful.  Most of the time we want to treat variables as first measured without loss of information. Being tallest or 12th heaviest in a sample is not much information.

Comment: PCA finds all the eigenvectors and eigenvalues (not just those with the largest eigenvalues). Whether you care about them all is another matter. There are some contexts in which PCs with the lowest eigenvalues are those to look at first.

Comment: @NickCox good point, edited

Comment: @NickCox regarding the point about ranks, I suppose an example where 
Spearman would be preferable (and without information loss) is when the entities are on an equally spaced grid?

Comment: There is always information loss. If you tell me the ranks in that case, or any other, I can't tell you the original values.

Comment: @NickCox If my values are (1,2,3,4) then the ranks are also (1,2,3,4) and there is no information loss.

Comment: Agreed: **if you look at the data too** then in some instances you can see that Pearson correlation would give the same answer. But you can't infer the data just from the ranks. Similarly you can't invert PCA results based on ranks to get back to the data. If someone tells you the answers to a test, you can get a perfect score. In itself, that doesn't gauge knowledge.

Comment: Imagine two Spearman PCAs based on height and weight for for two sets of  people. How do you compare them?

Comment: Agree with all what's said already by @Nick. Linear PCA your Q is about is a linear transform of data and is also based on Pearson r which is also linear summarization of data. Spearman rho is like Pearson r, but after ranking of the data. The tie between the pre-rank data and the PCA results will be lost. As for Kendall tau, it is not [SSCP-type](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22520/3277) similarity at all and linear PCA would be weird to use with it. Linear PCA mathematically makes sense only with SSCP-type measures.

Comment: Questions similar to yours were already asked on this site, mostly about factor analysis ([such as](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/141646/3277)), but they are relevant for PCA too.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the correlations. Pearson's correlation is a linear measure and the hypothesis test for it (`cor.test` in R, for example) assumes (approximate) Normal distributions of the input data. This makes the corresponding hypothesis test ("is my correlation coefficient 'significantly' different from 0?") a *parametric* test. Spearman's rank correlation coefficient uses the ranks only, it has no distributional assumptions, the corresponding hypothesis test will thus be a *non-parametric* test.

When you say that "a Spearman PCA does this with the Spearman correlation matrix, and therefore the dimensions are not only linearly uncorrelated, but monotonically uncorrelated. At least to me, that seems much stronger." you probably refer to the fact that a non-parametric hypothesis testing procedure is more robust than the corresponding parametric variant in the sense that the former has no distributional assumptions. The price that you pay, however, is reduced power (because "you know less", in this case by "throwing away" the actual data and keeping only their relative order).

I suspect one of the reasons why the Pearson PCA is "more popular" is that the Pearson's correlation coefficient is "more popular", perhaps because of the higher power of the corresponding hypothesis test *if the Normality assumption is approximately correct*.

Note, however, that the "popularity" of a scientific method depends on psychological and societal factors to a not inconsiderable extent. What is taught at universities in 1950 will influence what is written in textbooks in 1960 which will largely determine what will be taught in 1970, .... :-)

So maybe there's no good reason to it other than "this is what we got accustomed to."

Comment: A PCA that is followed by hypothesis testing can be done but is unusual and contrary to the exploratory and data-reduction spirit in which PCA is usually conducted.  BTW, *nothing* about Pearson correlation assumes Normality (although some hypothesis tests do, but they are irrelevant here).

Comment: @whuber "nothing about Pearson correlation assumes Normality", true. I meant the hypothesis test  (`cor.test` in R). Per manual: "If method is "pearson", the test statistic is based on Pearson's product moment correlation coefficient cor(x, y) and follows a t distribution with length(x)-2 degrees of freedom if the samples follow independent normal distributions." I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: +1 -- nice answer.  But it might be worth reconsidering the logic going from "using ranks throws away [information]" to "is less powerful," because that is not necessarily the case.  Power is subtler than that and depends on both the null and alternate hypotheses.  Indeed, tests of Pearson's $\rho$ can lack almost all power compared to tests of Spearman's $\rho$ when confronted with complex alternatives.

Comment: @whuber Yes, good point with the power -- admittedly I was oversimplifying matters. Thanks a lot for your comments BTW, they are very useful.